# How can Boolean/boolean serve as the key of a HashMap in Java?

Tags: java, collections, boolean

I have an interview question that asks if `Boolean` can serve as the key of a `HashMap` in Java. I wasn't sure how this was possible, and would like an explanation.

*It is also unclear if `boolean` or `Boolean` was meant in this question. Perhaps both should be handled in an answer.*

Comment: How? Convert it to an integer: `true` = 1, `false` = 0. You'd only be able to have two entries in the map...

Comment: I edited the question, but after reading @grexter89 answer, I'm not sure my edit is valid. Can you confirm if the question was about the primitive form of `boolean`?

Comment: You should kept the title as it is

Comment: The original title was: *"can we define boolean as a key in hashmap? How....Please explain me?"* There is no class called `hashmap` in Java. Should we assume he has a custom class called `hashmap` too since it is all lowercase?

Comment: As was mentioned by @Bohemian in another comment, [using `null` for the key is also acceptable](http://ideone.com/0NWuce). So, three entries are possible.

Comment: Repeating a comment from under my anwser: `mbs.put(null, "x")` in throwing an `NullPointerException.` What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a great (and pretty funny!) question. You're only going to have two items, but you can mash multiple items into each value. For example:

```
    import  java.util.ArrayList;
    import  java.util.Arrays;
    import  java.util.List;
    import  java.util.Map;
    import  java.util.TreeMap;
/**
   <P>{@code java BooleanKeyedMapXmpl}</P>
 **/
public class BooleanKeyedMapXmpl  {
   public static final void main(String[] igno_red)  {

        System.out.println("<Boolean,String>:");
            Map<Boolean,String> mbs = new TreeMap<Boolean,String>();

            mbs.put(true, "hello"); 
            mbs.put(false, "goodbye");

            System.out.println("true: " + mbs.get(true));
            System.out.println("false: " + mbs.get(false));
            System.out.println();

        System.out.println("<Boolean,ArrayList<String>>:");
            Map<Boolean,List<String>> mbls = new TreeMap<Boolean,List<String>>();

            mbls.put(true, new ArrayList<String>());
            mbls.put(false, new ArrayList<String>());

            List<String> lsTrue = mbls.get(true);
                lsTrue.add("hello1");
                lsTrue.add("hello2");
                lsTrue.add("hello3");
                lsTrue.add("hello4");
                lsTrue.add("hello5");

            List<String> lsFalse = mbls.get(false);
                lsFalse.add("goodbye1");
                lsFalse.add("goodbye2");
                lsFalse.add("goodbye3");
                lsFalse.add("goodbye4");
                lsFalse.add("goodbye5");

            System.out.println("true: " + Arrays.deepToString(lsTrue.toArray()));
            System.out.println("false: " + Arrays.deepToString(lsFalse.toArray()));
   }
}
```

Output:

```
[C:\java_code\]java BooleanKeyedMapXmpl
<Boolean,String>:
true: hello
false: goodbye

<Boolean,ArrayList<String>>:
true: [hello1, hello2, hello3, hello4, hello5]
false: [goodbye1, goodbye2, goodbye3, goodbye4, goodbye5]
```

Comment: As was mentioned by @Bohemian in another comment, [using `null` for the key is also acceptable](http://ideone.com/0NWuce). So, three entries are possible.

Comment: for suppose i want put more key,value pairs....Then what will be the output? 

if i print like this what will be the output?
<br>system.out.println(mbs);</br>

Comment: About to add the output.

Comment: Use `Arrays.deepToString(lsTrue.toArray())`

Comment: `mbs.put(null, "Kermit The Frog")` in throwing an `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @user3257654: Please comment here instead of editing my answer. I am happy to help.

Comment: I don't understand. The output is at the bottom of my answer. Just paste the into a new document and compile it. It should work for you. Then, on your own computer, feel free to tweak as you like!  :)

Answer (score 6):

Of course you can:

```
Map<Boolean,MyType> myMap = new HashMap<Boolean,MyType>();
myMap.put(true, newValue);     // Write
MyType t = myMap.get(boolKey); // Read
```

Autoboxing makes your job very simple - you don't even need to convert `boolean` to `Boolean`.

However, why bother with a map, when `boolean` has only two possible values? An array of two items and a simple conditional would perform better:

```
MyType[] myArrayMap = new MyType[2];
myArrayMap[key ? 1 : 0] = newValue; // Write
MyType t = myArrayMap[key ? 1 : 0]; // Read
```

Comment: I wouldn't bother talking about the alternative. The first half answers the question. It's not about common sense, it's a language question.

Comment: yes I think that the interviewer wants as answer that you can't use primitive types as keys

Comment: @Alessio Look in the question. It's  `Boolean serves`....and my assumptions are wrong sometime ;)

Comment: Also, you're wrong about it only having two values. `Boolean` can have three: `null` is a valid key for your map. Still +1, just fix it:)

Comment: when I read the question I thought that "boolean" was written, not "Boolean", maybe the post was edited? Anyway, it doesn't matter now :D

Comment: @Bohemian OP wrote "`boolean`", not "`Boolean`". I think it was an improper edit of the question.

Comment: The original title read *"can we define boolean as a key in hashmap? How....Please explain me?"*. I figured that he lowercased everything...and it wasn't intentional. That might've been wrong assumption on my part.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that.For instance

```
    Map<Boolean, String> selectedIds = new HashMap<Boolean, String>();
```

Usage ??

```
selectedIds.put(Boolean.TRUE, "stack");
selectedIds.put(Boolean.FALSE, "nostack");
```

Answer (score 3):

If it's about the Java class `java.util.HashMap<K,V>` you cannot, because `boolean` is a primitive type. You need to use classes such as `Boolean`

Comment: This is a good point, but I didn't get from his question that it was about the primitive form of `boolean` as opposed to the object form.

Comment: @crush You should ask him, or tell him.

Comment: @crush I didn't (really) get it either, that's why I mentioned `Boolean`. in the original post boolean was written with a small letter

Comment: Yeah, but in the original post everything was written with small letters, hah. I can see this question being about primitives in generics, or about generics period. It's hard to tell for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you mean Boolean, with a capital B. A HashMap can have any type as a key. If only Booleans are allowed, your map will only have two possible keys:

```
HashMap<Boolean, ?> map = new HashMap();
map.put(Boolean.TRUE, someObject);
map.put(Boolean.FALSE, someOtherObject);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Boolean primitives have a Boolean wrapper class aptly named Boolean. As always, the API is your best friend: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html But like crush said above, your map would then only have two entries, which seems strange.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you can.

```
Map<Boolean, String> myMap = new HashMap<Boolean, String>();
        myMap.put(true, "A");
        myMap.put(false, "D");
```

Comment: yes....but when i used to run this with the multiple insertions...in output am getting only two key and value pairs<br>
<br>
i.e., 
<br>
HashMap<Boolean, Integer>hm=new HashMap<Boolean, Integer>();<br>
  hm.put(true, 10);<br>
  hm.put(false, 50);<br>
  hm.put(true, 60);<br>
  hm.put(false, 80);<br>
  hm.put(true, 90);<br>
  hm.put(true, 90);<br>
  hm.put(false, 70);<br>
  hm.put(true, 10);<br>
  hm.put(false, 50);<br>
  System.out.println("Hashmap Values:"+hm);<br>
<br><br><br>

OUTPUT: Hashmap Values:{false=50, true=10}

Comment: Go through the put method inside the HashMap. Its clearly mentioned in the method's comment : "Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map. If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced."